# Is there a way to have divs "greedily" grab width?

Tags: css

I have 2 divs that are side by side. They are both closable via jquery. When they are both visible, they have a fixed width, but when one is closed, I want the remaining div to expand to eat up the width that the closed div used to take up. Is there a way to do this using just CSS (aside from the close button), or do I have to resort to javascript?

Comment: sir i think without java script its not possible

Comment: Could you not just give the divs width: auto and then remove the arbitrary width on a div when it's closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only method I could see for solving this with CSS would be to add classes to the containing element:

```
<div id="container" class="left|right|both">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Style the contents depending on what the parent class is. If `left` is the class, you give the first `div` a non-restricted width and hide the second `div`. The same goes for `right` and the second `div`. When the parent is `both`, you give both divs 50%.

All your JavaScript would need to do is handle which class is currently applied to the container.

Answer (score 1):

You need to atleast write one line of javascript for this and then you can use css for the effect.

Using jquery, toggle a class to the parent of divs whenever you click on the close. Find the jquery code for the click on the close button and add

```
$("#parent").toggle("classname");
```

Use css like

```
#parent div { width: /*fixed*/100px; }
#parent.classname div { width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="right">div2</div>
    <div class="left">Lorem  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam semper porta  sem, at ultrices ante interdum at. Donec condimentum euismod consequat.  Ut viverra lorem pretium nisi malesuada a vehicula urna aliquet. Proin  at ante nec neque commodo bibendum. Cras bibendum egestas lacus, nec  ullamcorper augue varius eget.</div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="remove">Remove Div 2</button>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:green;
}
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    background:red;
}​
​
```

JS:

```
$('#remove').on('click', function() {
    var div2 = $('.right')
    //div2.hide('slow');  // you could hide it as well  
    div2.remove();
});​
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/9Q86Y/

Answer (score -1):

***Edit***

You could mimic tables by using

```
display:table
```

and

```
display:table-cell
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/DUx3W/ (hat tip: @Jimmy Breck-McKye).

My original table fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6KkRL/

Comment: Actually, CSS's handling of layout is fine. We've had display: table and the layout module for years. It's the browser support. In any case, even clumsy CSS trumps tables for maintainability.

Comment: So are you saying this is possible with CSS? Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Sure, look at http://jsfiddle.net/DUx3W/ with Chrome/FF/IE8+ to see the display:table module in action.

Comment: Good idea. I forgot about display:table and display:table-cell. Updated my answer to remove the rant and be actually useful. :)